# Why is Row Overflow not working on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, varchar

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with a table that has around 860 columns. Aside from the ID column all other columns are varchar(N) where N is either 100 or 500. Upon inserting a new row (via an InfoPath form as the front end) with more than 8000 characters the SQL server returns the following error:

```
Cannot create a row of size 11024 which is greater than the allowable maximum of 8060.
```

From what I understand this should not be happening due to [Row Overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Can anyone please provide some insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Which column is the clustered index? ID?

Comment: Yes, the ID column is a clustered index.

Comment: Are you on sql 2000 compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a warning message.  You can verify that rows are overflowing to the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA pages by using the undocumented command DBCC IND.

Personally this sounds like a table which could stand some normalization.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not just a warning and that it is stopping the row from being inserted. I have tried to execute an INSERT query with more than 8060 bytes through Management Studio and received the following error:

`Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create a row of size 22689 which is greater than the allowable maximum of 8060.
The statement has been terminated.`. 

The table could definitely be normalized but there are some technical & business constraints that are not allowing this.

Comment: Does the table have a clustered index on it?  Is it the ID column?

Comment: I had initially thought that InfoPath could not interact with related tables. It turns out that it can. So to resolve the problem I normalized the database as mrdenny had suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> In SQL 2005, surpassing the 8,060 row size limit may impact
> performance. This is because SQL Server still maintains a limit of 8
> KB per page. When a combination of varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or
> sql_variant columns exceeds this limit, SQL Server moves the record
> column with the largest width to another page, while maintaining a
> 24-byte pointer on the original page.
>
> Moving large records to another page happens dynamically as records
> are lengthened based on update operations. Update operations that
> shorten records may result in records moved back to the original page.
> In addition, querying and performing other select operations such as
> sorts or joins on large records that contain row-overflow data slows
> processing time.

[more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msdnts/row-size-limitation-in-sql-2000-and-2005)

[Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186981(v=sql.105))

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

**ADDED:**

Set the [sp_tableoption stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 'large value types out of row' option to ON to store the field off page.

Comment: All 3 articles that you posted indicate that the query should be possible. Would you be able to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @cmcg Set the sp_tableoption stored procedure 'large value types out of row' option to ON to store the field off page.

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning, not an error. As long as the row is within the 2GB (I believe) limit, it should have inserted. Can you verify that it was indeed inserted?

Comment: I put in the wrong error message in question. I have updated this. My apologies.

Comment: That's odd. What compatibility level is the database running under?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 (90)