# Generating large strings for test data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was recently trying to create some large strings containing generic test data for [a question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4736/2626).  It seems that I used to know of a way to multiply a string.  However, I can no longer remember the syntax.

I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT 'A' + ('a' * 1000) + 'ha!'
```

To come up with "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaha!"  (Well, much longer, of course.)

Is this possible in T-SQL? (Or am I thinking of some other language?)  Also, are there any other techniques to generate large strings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`REPLICATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx):

```
SELECT 'A' + REPLICATE('a', 1000) + 'ha!';
```

If you need to go beyond 8,000 bytes (4,000 characters for varchar, or 8,000 characters for nvarchar), you'll need to manually `CONVERT` as Mark suggested in the comment below:

```
SELECT  'X' + REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'Y'),    9000) + 'Z';
SELECT N'X' + REPLICATE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N''), 5000) + N'Z';
```

Comment: Note that you'll have to provide a (MAX) input character to generate strings larger than 8060 characters: SELECT REPLICATE(CAST('a' AS varchar(MAX)), 15000). Make sure to cast it to nvarchar(MAX) if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Mark. There are other potential issues with `REPLICATE` too, depending on how Richard will use it (e.g. it can behave differently when using length of varchar vs. char), which is why I hot-linked the `REPLICATE` keyword to point to the documentation, instead of trying to regurgitate all of the potential gotchas from the documentation here.